# How to Display Particulate range of image from list in CarouselSlider.builder in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, api

I want to display Images from list in CarouselSlider.builder from index 1 to 3.

Here as below I got all Data from Api in _imageList.

```
List<ImageModel> _imageList = [];

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    ApiHelper().getImageList().then((images) {
      setState(() {
        _imageList = images;
      });
    });
  }
```

Here is my Image Slider Code as below.

```
CarouselSlider.builder(
                              itemCount: _imageList.length,
                              itemBuilder:
                                  (BuildContext context, int index, realindex) {
                                return Image.network(
                                  "$imageUrl" + _imageList[index].imgPath!,
                                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 40,
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                );
                              },
                              options: CarouselOptions(
                                viewportFraction: 1,
                                enlargeCenterPage: true,
                                initialPage: 1,
                              ),
                            ),
```

So how can i do this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your initState method you can just create a [sublist](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-core/List/sublist.html) of the `images` list so your imageList only contains the indices 1-3.

```dart
_imageList = images.sublist(1, 4);
```

Comment: Thank you. But if i want to display using condition, so how i can do this?

Comment: Do you want to filter the list by condition or just hide the Image and return something else instead in the item builder? Your Carousel builder will build _imageList.length items.